# Surface of spheres with the transformation formula

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\omega_n$ the measure of the surface (as obtained with the surface measure) of the unit sphere in $n$ dimensions. E.g. $\omega_2 = 2\pi$. Now let $n\ge 3$.

I want to obtain a formula for the surface $A(r)$ of the set $S_r := \{\,x\,\,\lvert \,\,\|x\| \le r \}$ (i.e. the surface measure of the set $\partial S_r$), and I want to use the transformation formula for this. Somehow I always get confused and can't manage to find it out... The result should be $A(r) = r^{n-1}\omega_n$. Can you even use the transformation formula for this?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:
By 'transformation formula', I mean this formula: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables

Comment: Just a question: what is the transformation formula, for you?

Comment: Sorry, I naively translated the german word "Transformationsformel" into English. What I mean is this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we have the natural embedding $S^{n-1}\subset{\mathbb R}^n$; whence the unit circle $S^1\subset{\mathbb R}^2$ is the $1$-sphere. Its length serves as $\omega_1=2\pi$. Then  $S^2\subset{\mathbb R}^3$ is the "ordinary" unit sphere and has $\omega_2=4\pi$.

For geometric reasons the $n$-dimensional area of the $n$-sphere of radius $r>0$ is given by  $\omega_n r^n$, where $\omega_n$ is the area of the $n$-dimensional unit sphere. Therefore it suffices to compute the numbers $\omega_n$ for all $n\geq1$. When you speak about a "transformation formula" then you most probably have a parametric representation of each of these spheres in mind. Using this and the so called *Gram determinant* (an essential ingredient for computing higher dimensional areas) we would in fact be able to compute the numbers $\omega_n$, resp. to derive a recursion formula for the $\omega_n$.

But in the special case of spheres there is a much simpler, more "geometric" procedure available. Denote by $\kappa_n$ the volume of the $n$-dimensional unit ball $B=B_1^n$. Then an $n$-ball of radius $r>0$ will have volume $\kappa_n\, r^n$. Consider now two concentric $n$-balls of radius $1$ and $1+\epsilon$. Then
$${\rm vol}\,(B_{1+\epsilon})-{\rm vol}\,(B_1)={\rm vol}\,(B_{1+\epsilon}\setminus B_1)\doteq \epsilon\,\omega_{n-1}\ ,$$
because the difference set is roughly a spherical shell of radius $1$ and thickness $\epsilon$. It follows that
$$\omega_{n-1}=\lim_{\epsilon\to0+}{\kappa_n(1+\epsilon)^n - \kappa\, 1^n\over\epsilon} = n\,\kappa_n\ .$$

Therefore we need a formula for the volumes $\kappa_n$. One has $\kappa_1=2$ and $\kappa_2=\pi$; furthermore the $\kappa_n$ satisfy the the recursion
$$\kappa_n={2\pi\over n}\ \kappa_{n-2}\qquad(n\geq3)\ .$$
To prove this recursion we write the points of ${\mathbb R}^n$ in the form $(x,y,{\bf z})$ with $x$, $y\in{\mathbb R}$, ${\bf z}\in{\mathbb R}^{n-2}$. Since
$$B_1^n=\bigl\{(x,y,{\bf z})\ \bigm|\ (x,y)\in B_1^2, \ {\bf z}\in {B_{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}^{n-2}}\bigr\}\ ,$$
we can write
$$\kappa_n=\int_{B_1^n} 1\ {\rm d}{\bf x}=\int_{B_1^2}\ \int_{B_{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}^{n-2}}\ {\rm d}({\bf z})\ {\rm d}(x,y)\ .$$
The inner integral has the value $\kappa_{n-2} (1-r^2)^{(n-2)/2}$, where $r:=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$; and writing ${\rm d}(x,y)=2\pi r\ dr$ in the outer integral leads to the stated formula.

Writing $\kappa_n$, resp. $\omega_n$, in terms of the $\Gamma$-function allows of a unified formula for $\omega_n$, valid for all $n\geq0$.